# Display list of controls with fluid width in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created panel which displays controls. However I want the list of controls to always fit the width of the window. Similar to how visual studios Properties panel works. I'm assuming by using listbox I'll automatically inherit the scrollbar when the controls become lengthy.

What i have **now on the left** and the **goal on the right**.

[image]
[image]

This is visual studios.

[image]

My code behind looks like this...

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="AssetList" ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" SelectionMode="Extended">
            <ListBox.Resources>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:IntAttr}">
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Blue"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text=" "></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBlock>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: how did you place your ChckBox? could you show a XAML?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             Grid.Column="0" 
             x:Name="AssetList" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" 
             SelectionMode="Extended">....
```